# Importrange (or maybe another part of formula) behaves differently after a short time period

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, vlookup

I am using this formula to look for data in column F related to data in column A between two spreadsheets.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; {IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetID";"sheet1!A4:A")\ IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetID";"sheet1!F4:F")}; 2; 0);))
```

for some reason after some while (minutes to days) the formula stops working and I need to change the sheet name from SHEET1 to 'SHEET1' and it starts working again.
BUT after some time I need to change that back to only SHEET1 because it stopped working again and needs a change to be done.

Reason for this instead of

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A;IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetID";"sheet1!A4:F"); 6; 0);))
```

is because this seems to take a lot less time to import since it's only minding two columns instead of A and F PLUS all between those two. And also because sometimes I am using the same formula for columns like DF and that's a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the above formulas may work for you, in case of huge imported arrays is better to import them separately in a sheet as:

A1: **`=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetID";"sheet1!A4:A")`**
B1: **`=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetID";"sheet1!F4:F")`**

and then use it in **`VLOOKUP`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; 'hiddenimportsheet'!A:B; 2; 0)))
```

This will slightly improve the performance and luckily solve your issue.

Comment: hmmm, interesting. When I use A4:A it gives me "internal error importing range" but A:A works just fine (but it also imports the unwanted first four cells/rows obviously). Does that mean there is some problem with the source spreadsheet? Unfortunately I cannot share these two specific spreadsheets and I suspect this is somewhat not possible to redo for test sheets

Comment: the only thing what comes to my mind is sheetname. make sure that formula uses exactly the same one (caps-wise like too) and also make sure you have enough rows. if sheet name does not have spaces you dont need to wrap it into single quotes ' '

Comment: The source spreadsheet has 1912 rows out of which 1419 are filled with data, target spreadsheet had also 1912, tried to have enough so now has 3823. I have tried A4:A1912 and it works perfectly but A4:A simply doesn't. I am clueless. Sheet name is exactly the same as in formula.

Comment: Anyway, I have imported it with A:A and F:F (and so on) and it works great so far, hopefully it stays like this. Thank you for your help!